# Cadena de caracteres capicua java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que diga si la frase introducida o palabra es capicua, es decir holaloh. Lo que hago son dos for, que empiece a recorrer desde el inicio y el otro desde el final, y después guardarlos con el charAt y la posición del indice pero me lo hace bien en algunas palabras y en otras no. No se si hay algo mal en el código.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class capicua {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Escriba una cadena.");
    String x = teclado.nextLine();
    int s = x.length();
    int z = s / 2;
    char k;
    char m;

    for (int i = 0; i <= z; i++) {
        for (int j = (s - 1); j>z ; j--) {

            k = x.charAt(i);
            m = x.charAt(j);

            if (k==m) {
                System.out.println("Bien.");
            }

        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no es necesario que user for anidado, no estabas comparando como deberia ser la comparacion para este problema, lo cual es comparar

> el primer elemento con el ultimo
>
> el segundo elemento con el penultimo
>
> el tercer elemento con el antepenultimo
>   etc.

tu **error** radica en la comparacion: **lo que tu codigo hace es:**

> **i=0**
>   comparar el primer elemento con el ultimo elemento
>
> comparar el primer elemento con el penultimo elemento
>
> comparar el primer elemento con el antepenultimo elemento ...
>
> **i=1**
>   comparar el segundo elemento con el ultimo elemento
>
> comparar el segundo elemento con el penultimo elemento
>
> comparar el segundo elemento con el antepenultimo elemento ...
>
> **i=2**
>
> comparar el tercer elemento con el ultimo elemento
>
> comparar el tercer elemento con el penultimo elemento
>
> comparar el tercer elemento con el antepenultimo elemento ...etc

**te dejo una solucion:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class capicua {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    String x = "anitalavalatina";
    int s = x.length();
    int z = s / 2;
    char k;
    char m;
    int p=0;

        for (int j = (s - 1); j>z && p<z ; j--) {

            k = x.charAt(p);
            m = x.charAt(j);

      System.out.println(k+" "+m );   

            if (k==m) {
                System.out.println("Bien.");
            }
          p++;

        }

  }
}
```

Comment: Ya entendí, muchas gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Si no tienes limitaciones para utilizar `StringUtils` el código te va a quedar mucho más reducido:

```
String prueba = "prueba";
String aux = StringUtils.reverse(prueba);
System.out.println(String.format("'%s' %s es palíndromo: '%s'", prueba, (prueba.equals(aux)?"SI":"NO"),aux));

prueba = "acurruca";
aux = StringUtils.reverse(prueba);
System.out.println(String.format("'%s' %s es palíndromo: '%s'", prueba, (prueba.equals(aux)?"SI":"NO"),aux));
```

Nos da la siguiente salida:

> 'prueba' NO es palíndromo: 'abeurp'
>   'acurruca' SI es palíndromo: 'acurruca'

*NOTA: Cuando nos referimos a palabras se usa la expresión [palíndromo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pal%C3%ADndromo) para lo que buscas en vez de capicúa que se usa para numerales.*